# Stripe Rails: Invalid integer: 1.06

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I can't get my head around this one.

My form passes a params of `106` which is `£1.06`.

[image]

Charging the card:

```
amount = params[:amount].to_f
begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => amount / 100,
    :currency => "gbp",
    :source => token,
    :description => "Example charge"
  )
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  # The card has been declined
end
```

How to prevent:

> Invalid integer: 1.06

Where does the integer comes from? I have converted that to `float`.

Comment: I can't say exactly what's happened, without more information.... But it looks like somewhere, your code is expecting `amount` to be an `Integer` (and you're giving it a `Float`). My first guess is that in the `Stripe::Charge` model, you have a rails validation, which checks that the value is an integer? Or maybe the database table column type is `integer`?

Comment: If I remove the `.to_f`, stripe will charge £106 instead of £1.06. My js is ok as the params it passes is `106`. I'll restart this server in a bit.

Comment: Could you please post the params[:amount] value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby) amount parameter should be integer and it is perceived as cents. So you should pass `params[:amount]` directly as amount.

```
begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => params[:amount],
    :currency => "gbp",
    :source => token,
    :description => "Example charge"
  )
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  # The card has been declined
end
```

Comment: Totally forgot the documentation. I was using this from an old Polymer project.